# A slowly growing sequence ($ \sim \log \sqrt{n}$) related to factorization of integers

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, algorithms, prime-numbers

Set $a_0=n$, if it's prime, stop, if it's composite find the largerst factor not equal to $n$, and call it $b_0$, then set $a_1=b_0+\frac{a_0}{b_0}$. Run the algorithm with $a_1$. Call the number of runs $A_n$.

We have $A_4= \infty$, but for any other positive integer the number of runs should be finite.

For example:

$$14 \to \begin{cases} 7 \\ 2 \end{cases} \to 9 \to \begin{cases} 3 \\ 3 \end{cases} \to 6 \to \begin{cases} 3 \\ 2 \end{cases} \to 5$$

Thus, $A_{14}=3$.

The sequence of $A_n$ for $n \geq 5$ starts like this:

`0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 3, 0, 3, 3, 2, 0, 1, 0, 4, 2, 1, 0, 4, 2, 4, 4, 3, 0, 1, 0, 2, 4, 1, 4, 5, 0, 3, 3, 2, 0, 1, 0, 5, 2, 3, 0, 5, 4, 5, 5, 4, 0, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 0, 3, 0, 5, 5, 2, 2, 5, 0, 6, 5, 1, 0, 4, 0, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 6, ...`

If we plot the average (partial sums divided by $n$), the order of growth seems to be very close to $\log \sqrt{n}$.

[image]

I couldn't find the sequence in OEIS, thus I wanted to ask:

> Was this sequence studied before? Can we prove the order of growth on average?

Any other isights or references are appreciated.

Comment: The question seems pretty arbitrary / uninteresting to me. What is the motivation? Why do we care about the map which takes $n$ to $a + b$ where $ab = n$ and $a$ is as large as possible but not $n$?

Comment: Well, finding the largest factor not equal to $n$ is the same as finding the _smallest_ factor not equal to 1, and that is at least 2, so the number of steps is at most about $\log_2n$. BTW, the argument values at which new records are reached look awfully like $2^k+4$.

Comment: @IvanNeretin, thank you for your comment